# CSS href styling - all in one

Tags: css

I beg your pardon , for I suppose the answer is simple, though I swear I did reserach and found nothing.

I want to style a hyperlink but instead of making in this way:

```
#div a:link {color: #fff; text-decoration: underline}
#div a:visited {color: #fff; text-decoration: none}
#div a:active {color: #fff; text-decoration: none}
#div a:hover {color: #f5f5f5; text-decoration: none;}
```

I'd like to have it done this way to save time as I need only one particular style for all (hover, active, link and visited):

```
#div a:link, #div a:visited, #div a:acive, #div a:hover  {color: #fff; text-decoration: underline}
```

Comment: Is the second line not working? Can you be more specific with your question?

Comment: do you want a:hover to have color #fff or #f5f5f5?

Comment: nope - the second line doesn't work (I made a mistake - extra comma in tehe xample though even proper version doesn't seem to eb working.

More specfic:
insteda of styling all four states (link, visited, hover and active) SEPARATELY I'd like to have them all styled IN ONE LINE (I just need them all to be, say, white + underlined
That's it.

Comment: You have an extra trailing comma in your definition of the second line right before the declaration. This causes a syntax error and thus it will not get executed. Also, there is no `a:acive` state, this should be `a:active`.

Comment: Mauricio - all states should be #fff...both hover and link...

Comment: @Timusan  - I know about teh comma.. added it here by mistake. It doesn't work without teh comma too.

`#div a:link, #div a:visited, #div a:acive, #div a:hover  {color: #fff; text-decoration: underline}`

NOPE =(

Comment: @Rossitten Do you actually have a div with an id `#div`? Or are you trying to simply target every div `element`?

Comment: I do have. Thanks Timusan, this was sorted out - please check the answer. Thanks for your help  -it's really appreciated, mate

Comment: No problem, happy @Cattla and @Cai could answer it for you! However, I still wonder why your syntax did not seem to work (after you correct the `a:active` pseudo selector and trailing comma), that syntax should do the trick as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#div a{color: #fff; text-decoration: underline}
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to the code in the question. If this is the accepted answer, then the intended question was different from what was actually asked.

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
#div a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks-  yess!!! so damn simple. I knew it is doable and it is simple...thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want them all the same, then use this:

```css
#div {
  background: black;
  }

#div a:link,


#div a:visited,


#div a:active,


#div a:hover {


  color: #fff;


  text-decoration: underline


}
```

```html
<div id="div"><a href="#">hello</a>
  <br/>
  <a href="#">hello</a>
  <br/>
  <a href="#">hello</a>
  <br/>
  <a href="#">hello</a>
  <br/>
  <a href="#">hello</a>
</div>
```

I made the background black so you could see better.